# Execute Windows SC command as another user

Tags: command-line-interface, windows-service, windows

I would like to execute the SC command against a network target as a different user.  I need to be able to specify username and password on the commandline as well, as this is for scripting purposes.  However, I see no options on SC for executing a command as another user.  I see the 'obj' option which accepts a username, but that appears to be for setting the user account under which the service itself should run under.

If there is no way to change the user-context of the execution, is there another command that will allow me to create/start/stop a windows service in a scriptable manner (calling from TeamCity)

Comment: Are the to machines joined to the same domain?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, would be supplying domain\username as the username ideally

Answer (score 7):

Use the ["RunAs" commandline tool](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html), it lets you supply an explicit credential set, and supports both "Domain\Username" and UPN formatting, allowing you to authenticate as another user and the run your command:

```
   Runas /user:Domain\user "sc \\remoteServer stop serviceKeyName"
```

---

### Alternative:

[Set up a scheduled task](http://poundcomment.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/how-to-create-a-whitelist-uac-for-windows-7/) with a specific logon account

Comment: Unfortunately this command does not allow one to specify the password in the command line, it can only be provided when prompted after execution.  Hence, is not scriptable.

Comment: Maybe useful to change windows service credential in remote Server.

Comment: runAs tool similar in SysInternals ? Who's support that tool ?

Answer (score 3):

Ended up installing and using PsExec - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.  Allows for inline specification of username/password, so is scriptable.

Comment: Works Psexec to change windows service credential in remote Server ?

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell:

```
(get-wmiobject win32_service -comp servername -cred domain\user -filter "name='browser'").stopservice()
```

`-cred` will pop up a credentials dialog box also

Replace `servername`, `domain\user` and the `name=` with proper values

with `-cred` you can even used stored credentials.